# How can I put differents elements in my arrayAdapter?

Tags: android, sugarorm

my problem is:

I have a sugar database with diferents columns, and I want to put in my list view this diferents columns how can I?

This is my code(FragmentPlanList.java):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


import net.elinformaticoenganchado.sergio.workout.entity.Plan;

import java.util.List;

public class FragmentPlanList extends ListFragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plan_list, container, false);

        if(Plan.count(Plan.class) == 0){

        } else{
            List<Plan> plans = Plan.listAll(Plan.class);
            ArrayAdapter<Plan> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_template, R.id.list_template_name, plans);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            plans.toArray();
            System.out.println(plans);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my plan_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my row for listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/list_template_example"
        android:fontFamily="Arial"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/list_template_name" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"
        android:fontFamily="Arial"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/list_template_duration"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to put Plans.name (example) into TextView with id list_template_name and Plan.duration into TextView with id list_template_duration.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Add data base entity:

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;
import com.orm.dsl.NotNull;
import com.orm.dsl.Unique;

public class Plan extends SugarRecord{

    @Unique
    protected String name;
    @NotNull
    protected Integer duration;
    @NotNull
    protected String description;

    public Plan() {
    }

    public Plan(String name, Integer duration, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * @return String name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return Integer duration
     */
    public Integer getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    /**
     * @param duration
     */
    public void setDuration(Integer duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    /**
     * @return String duration
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * @param description
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Plan{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", duration=" + duration +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own Adapter, extending  ArrayAdapter with a specific type, or you can use type Object, so you can add what ever you want.

then you will have to use instanceof in order to test what kind of Object the current element is. So you will be able to apply a particular style, load a particular layout, in order to render this object.

Exemple

```
public class ObjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
    public ObjectAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position


        try {
            Object object = getItem(position);
            // TODO: Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            if (object instance Plan) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.plan_item, parent, false);
                }

                Plan plan = (Plan) object; // cast the object to a Plan

                // populate view with data
                TextView planTitleTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_template_name);
                ImageView planImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id. list_template_duration);

                planNameTV.setText(plan.name);
                planDurationTV.setText(plan.duration);

            } else if (object instance PlanB) { // Optional
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.plan_b_item, parent, false);

                PlanB plan = (PlanB) object; // cast the object to a Plan

                // populate view with data
                TextView planTitleTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plan_b_title);
                ImageView planImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plan_b_image);

                planTitleTV.setText(plan.title);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: note: you can you ArrayAdapter<Plan> if you have only Plan in your list. that prevent to have to cast.

Comment: one more thing I am trying to call this class but is not working 

List<Plan> plans = Plan.listAll(Plan.class);
            PlanAdapter adapter = new PlanAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_template, plans);

I have the same code like you but the only change is that i have a list not an arrayList

Comment: what error do you get ? you have to set the adapter to your list view:  adapter = new PlanAdapter(this.getActivity(), plans);
setListAdapter(adapter); do it in you onCreate()

Comment: Oh sorry yes I forget setAdapter :D, Thanks!